# Pycharm Database for SQlite converts date and datetime columns to long integers

Tags: sqlite, pycharm

[image]

I am trying to export this database but whenever I try to make a row and add a date Pycharm database turns it into an integer and it cant export

Answer (score 1):

According to the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2570) on the JetBrains issue board, this seems to be a common problem. But can be solved by setting the **date_class** in the SQLite driver.

In the "*Database*" tool window, open the Data Source properties window "*Data Sources and Drivers*" and select the tab "*Drivers*" > the entry "*SQLite*" > tab "*Advanced*" > **Set `date_class` to value `TEXT`**.

[image: Change of date_class for PyCharm SQLite driver]

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the JetBrains issue, I also had to edit the `date_string_format` setting.